# Is there a difference between a jewel set with gems and one embedded with gems?

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference

Is there a difference between a jewel *set* with gems and one *embedded* with gems?

I was wondering if the two terms were interchangeable since their definitions look pretty much the same—obviously within the context of jewelry only.

Is it just a question of formality or is there an actual physical difference?

An [ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=set%20with%20gems%2Cembedded%20with%20gems&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cset%20with%20gems%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cembedded%20with%20gems%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cset%20with%20gems%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cembedded%20with%20gems%3B%2Cc0) shows that "set" is much more used than "embedded", but it might be bacause of a slight difference in meaning.

Comment: I don't think this is a question of general English use, so much as specialist terminology among jewellers. I don't think there's any difference, but that would be best answered by someone in the trade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Set* is the word usually used for the technique of placing gemstones securely in a piece of jewellery. *Embed* is a more general term for an item which has been fixed into a substance.

A jewel thickly covered with gems is sometimes said to be *encrusted* with them.